# is there pycharm interpretor setting equivalent with vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, pycharm

is there pycharm interpretor setting equivalent with vscode?[image]

I want to set as virtual environment like this in vscode.

Comment: How are things going? Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use "`python -m venv venv`" in the terminal of VSCode to create a virtual environment named "`venv`", and select the created virtual environment from the lower left corner of VSCode:

[image]

You could refer to: [virtual environment in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_global-virtual-and-conda-environments).